# admin-on-rest - show a list with a filter form without a button

Tags: admin-on-rest

I am trying to use admin-on-rest to display a list with a filter form, but without the filter button. I followed the documentation and added a "context='form'" parameter to the filter. I am getting this exception:

Edit: I added alwaysOn as suggested and the form components are rendered twice. see attached screenshot.

[image]

```
proxyConsole.js:56 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `hideFilter` is marked as required in `FilterForm`, but its value is `undefined`.
in FilterForm (created by Form(FilterForm))
in Form(FilterForm) (created by Connect(Form(FilterForm)))
in Connect(Form(FilterForm)) (created by ReduxForm)
in ReduxForm (created by getContext(ReduxForm))
in getContext(ReduxForm) (created by Filter)
in Filter (at index.js:31)
in CommandFilter (at index.js:49)
in div (created by CardActions)
in CardActions (created by onlyUpdateForKeys(Actions))
in onlyUpdateForKeys(Actions) (created by List)
in div (created by Card)
in div (created by Paper)
in Paper (created by Card)
in Card (created by List)
in div (created by List)
in List (created by getContext(List))
in getContext(List) (created by Connect(getContext(List)))
in Connect(getContext(List)) (at index.js:49)
in CommandList (created by Route)
in Restricted (created by Connect(Restricted))
in Connect(Restricted) (created by Route)
in Route (created by CrudRoute)
in Switch (created by CrudRoute)
in CrudRoute (created by Route)
in Route (created by AdminRoutes)
in Switch (created by AdminRoutes)
in AdminRoutes (created by Layout)
in div (created by Layout)
in div (created by Layout)
in div (created by Layout)
in div (created by Layout)
in MuiThemeProvider (created by Layout)
in Layout (created by WithWidth)
in EventListener (created by WithWidth)
in WithWidth (created by Connect(WithWidth))
in Connect(WithWidth) (created by Connect(Connect(WithWidth)))
in Connect(Connect(WithWidth)) (created by Route)
in Route (created by Admin)
in Switch (created by Admin)
in div (created by Admin)
in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
in ConnectedRouter (created by Admin)
in TranslationProvider (created by withContext(TranslationProvider))
in withContext(TranslationProvider) (created by Connect(withContext(TranslationProvider)))
in Connect(withContext(TranslationProvider)) (created by Admin)
in Provider (created by Admin)
in Admin (at App.js:37)
in App (at index.js:16)
```

Comment: I think I understand you, you can use the url for that proposals not the filter or do you need the user interaction?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Sorry...

Comment: sorry for the confused answer. My point is that you can filter directly using a url see this example: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest-demo/blob/master/src/categories/LinkToRelatedProducts.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was adding "context=form". I just need to set all fields to alwaysOn. Now it renders correctly and the error is gone.

Thanks, wesley6j!

https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/750

Answer (score 1):

if you meant button Add Filter as in docs https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Tutorial.html#filters then you can set option `alwaysOn` for filter.

```
const ClientFeedbackFilter = (props) => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <CheckboxGroupInput source="read" choices={[
        { id: 'true', name: 'Read' },
        { id: 'false', name: 'Unread' },
    ]} alwaysOn />
    <TextInput source="by_content" alwaysOn />
  </Filter>
);
```

Comment: I added alwaysOn and all the components are rendered twice. I'll edit my original question.

Comment: @barisdad just simple try to search where you place it twice. i think it maybe in App.js